# Foreach loop adding value is slightly off

Tags: javascript

I'm using angular foreach to add values, for example:

```
var total = 0;
var array = [    
    {"name":"1","value":4692725.79},
    {"name":"2","value":498019.86},
    {"name":"3","value":2205238.15}
];    

angular.forEach(array, function(o, n) {
    total += o.value;
});
```

total = `7395983.800000001` when the correct total should be `7395983.8`.

Any ideas??

Comment: [yep](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail/), 
http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: JavaScript uses floats ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript uses floats, always, see the link of @dmitry-ledentsov in the comments above.

To solve your issue, you can use either:

```
total.toFixed(2)
```

you will get a String Type with 2 decimals.

or you round your result at the end to the nearest integer, to get a precise Number Type:

```
Math.round(total)
```

Your choice, right choice depends what you wanna do with the result later.